# InfluxDB 2.0 How to find out how many queries are being executed

Tags: influxdb, influxql, influxdb-2

I'm using InfluxDB 2.0. Looking to go to the cloud in production when all my testing is done. I'm trying to evaluate the amount of queries my load is going to generate.

I would like to be able to know how much queries are generated by specific load of my application.

- How many INSERTS am I generating? (for example to be able to know if my bulk insert actually works or if individual inserts are generated.)
- How many SELECT queries are generated when I use a specific report?
- How many mb or gb of data is returned by my SELECT queries?
- How big is my data inside InfluxDB?

I need to be able to answer all of those questions to have a good estimate of the costs I will have in the cloud.

I'm fairly new to InfluxDB. I've read a lot of documentation and pages but I can't seem to find out how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I'm posting this here in case someone else is looking for the same answer.

If you are on a "on premise" server and not on the cloud, you need to follow this guide and install Telegraph.

This is what's going to allow you do get all the server statistics that you need.

https://www.influxdata.com/blog/getting-started-with-influxdb-2-0-scraping-metrics-running-telegraf-querying-data-and-writing-data/